# ShellExecuteEx and Coinitialize in VCL thread

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Do I need to call `Coinitialize` in the main/VCL thread in Delphi
before using [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154.aspx)?

For a thread, yes but for the VCL thread ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to call `CoInitialize` for Windows Forms Applications. 
This is done for you in the main thread.
More specific `TApplication.Create` in `Forms.Pas`:

```
...
if not IsLibrary then
 FNeedToUninitialize := Succeeded(OleInitialize(nil));
...
```

Comment: Isn't the initialization done in an InitProc during Application.Initialize?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: This is the only COM related initialization I could find in the source startup code(Delphi XE here).

Comment: I bet you'll find a call to CoInitializeEx in an initial proc.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I did a Grep on the source code, if you found something else, feel free to add it. Anyway `OleInitialize` calls `CoInitializeEx` internally.

Comment: I've added some more details in an answer of my own. I just want to do that for extra information. I take nothing away from your answer. The initialization that you highlight is the one that counts. +1

Answer (score 3):

If in doubt, do it. In either case, `CoInitialize()` will return a `hr : HRESULT` which you should check, because you need to `CoUninitialize()` on `SUCCEEDED(hr)`, but not when `FAILED(hr)`. A failed result usually indicates that it already has been called.

Cited from your MSDN ref:

> Nonetheless, it is good practice to always initalize COM before using
>   this function.

Comment: The question specifically asks to remove the doubt.

Comment: ... which can be done easily by checking the HRESULT.

Comment: Which would be the wrong way to do it. Trial and error is never better than easily discoverable and demonstrable facts.

Comment: @JensG, MSDN writes: "To close the COM library gracefully on a thread, each successful call to `CoInitialize` or `CoInitializeEx`, including any call that returns `S_FALSE`, must be balanced by a corresponding call to `CoUninitialize`", so that `CoUninitialize` must be called for both `S_OK` and `S_FALSE` results of `CoInitialize[Ex]`

Comment: @ALZ: Exactly, that's why we have macros/functions like `SUCCEEDED()`and `FAILED()` which you should use. And `S_FALSE` is an success code, thus `SUCCEEDED(S_FALSE)` evaluates to true.

Comment: @JensG, Thanks! I didn't know that "`SUCCEEDED(S_FALSE)` evaluates to true."
Live a century - learn a century! :)

Answer (score 3):

In the RTL/VCL source, COM is initialized in the following ways:

1. By a call to `OleInitialize` made from `Forms.TApplication.Create`. So this call will be made for all VCL forms applications, but not, for example, for service applications.
2. By a call to `CoInitialize` or `CoInitializeEx` in `ComObj.InitComObj`. This is registered as an `InitProc` in the `initialization` section of the `ComObj` unit. In turn, the call to `Application.Initialize` in your project .dpr file's code will invoke `ComObj.InitComObj`.
3. In many and various other locations around the RTL/VCL. Including, but not limited to, Datasnap, ComServ, Soap, System.Win.Sensors, Winapi.DirectShow9. Some of these areas of code are more recent than Delphi 7.

Now, of these various COM initializations, the ones that count are 1 and 2. In any standard VCL forms application, both of these will run at startup in the main thread. Item 1 runs first and so gets to initialize COM first. That's the initialization that counts. Item 2 runs after and returns `S_FALSE` meaning that COM was already initialized.

So, to your question:

> Do I need to call Coinitialize in the main/VCL thread?

No you do not. You can be sure that COM has already been initialized in a VCL application's main thread.