# Is there some known unit who automatically initialize the COM Library when it's used?

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-2009

I made a custom control that needs to use API `DoDragDrop` function and they say I must call `OleInitialize` before calling this function.

I do that in `MyControl.Create` method but I get `S_FALSE` result, so it means that the COM library is already initialized. But who initialize it ?

I do not initialize this before in my application. I am thinking, maybe there is some delphi unit who initialize it in his `initialization` section... And a secondary question is what should I do, should I continue initializing the COM Library in `MyControl.Create` method or should I not initialize at all (because it's already initialized) ?

Comment: `TApplication` does it for you. Since you are making a visual control, [all you need to do is this](http://i.imgur.com/Uk3IoaG.jpg).

Comment: So COM Library it's always initializated in every delphi application by default ?

Comment: Not every, but in VCL forms application it is so.

Comment: There are a number of other Windows controls which also require COM, so yes, VCL automatically initializes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20019023/505088) to a similar question:

> In the RTL/VCL source, COM is initialized in the following ways:
>
> 1. By a call to `OleInitialize` made from `Forms.TApplication.Create`. So this call will be made for all VCL forms applications, but not, for
>      example, for service applications.
> 2. By a call to `CoInitialize` or `CoInitializeEx` in `ComObj.InitComObj`. This is registered as an `InitProc` in the
>      `initialization` section of the `ComObj` unit. In turn, the call to
>      `Application.Initialize` in your project .dpr file's code will invoke
>      `ComObj.InitComObj`.
> 3. In many and various other locations around the RTL/VCL. Including, but not limited to, Datasnap, ComServ, Soap, System.Win.Sensors,
>      Winapi.DirectShow9. Some of these areas of code are more recent than
>      Delphi 7.
>
> Now, of these various COM initializations, the ones that count are 1
>   and 2. In any standard VCL forms application, both of these will run
>   at startup in the main thread. Item 1 runs first and so gets to
>   initialize COM first. That's the initialization that counts. Item 2
>   runs after and returns `S_FALSE` meaning that COM was already
>   initialized.

All VCL applications include the `Forms` unit and so you can be sure thaat COM is initialized in the main VCL thread. For other threads you need to initialize COM if necessary.

---

You must never initialize COM in control or more generally a thread that you are not in control of. If you do so then your initialization may conflict with the apartment type specified by the owner of the thread.

Comment: There is no check whether the `OleInitialize` call succeeded, so you cannot be sure until you call it by yourself. You can only hope.

Comment: @TLama if it failed then, it's going to fail again

Comment: Not with the `OLE_E_WRONGCOMPOBJ` failure (if you would update those libraries and call it again). But the chances are less than you'll be hit by a falling piano.